# How to resize/scale an image in Octave?

Tags: image, matlab, resize, scale, octave

Is there a built-in command to resize/scale a monochrome image (represented by an array of floats for instance) in Octave ?

If not, what would be a fast implementation for a basic algorithm with some amount of interpolation (bilinear let's say) ?
I actually only need to downsample my image (scale it down), which may simplify the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `imresize`.

You can see the documentation there:
http://www.mathworks.fr/help/toolbox/images/ref/imresize.html

Comment: Ah, thank you so much ! It works out of the box in Matlab. For Octave, although this function is not part of the base package, it is included in the "image" add-on package.

Answer (score -1):

You could extract some pixels? Tue example here creates a new pic with every second pixel of the original image.

```
extract = img(1:2:rowMax, 1:2:columnMax, :);
imshow(extract)
```

Comment: Please don't write answers in a way that makes them look like questions.
There are systems in place to check for Not An Answer (NAA) posts.
This answer was falsely picked up by one of them. Please consider editing it to look more like an answer.